# Python: use win32 library on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pywin32

there are paid solutions like [aspose](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net/) to transform file from a certain format to another.

It's seems really intuitive to be able to transform a .xlsx into a .pdf.

One solution could be to use win32.client.

To do so (I'm doing it on my local windows and it works like a charm).

So we need to use:

- a EC2 with Windows ? Checking in an S3 sometime, downloading the file, changing it and uploading it ?
- a lambda with a win32com layer ?
- a lambda with a docker with win32 ?
- something else ?

Comment: Aspose has a cloud API (https://websites.aspose.com/aspose/cloud) that could help.

Comment: "there are paid solutions like aspose to transform file from a certain format to another." I know. The purpose is to propose an alternative free solution. :p because I think it should be free. It's too general and too useful to stay unfree.

Comment: "So for free, some single person would need on your behest, to dedicate their lifetime to write that converter" Actually win32.client is free and does it well no ? I don't need the converter, I'm talking about the capacity to deploy the working converter into a lambda to make it easy to deploy as SaaS. ANd for that I need to create right env/docker and pack it as layer (and give it as public if I suceed).